# Bubble sort bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I am trying to sort a list of names and their scores in dictionary order in bash using bubble sort. The arrays are

```
Ted 86
Anthony 70
Mark 95
Kyle 65
David 75
```

The names are stored in an array names, and the scores are in an array scores

This is my code and its giving me an error on line 30 saying "to many arguments" and I cannot seem to find why.

```
#! /bin/bash
inputfile="$1"

if [[ !(-f "$1") ]]; then
    echo "$1 must be a file"
    exit 1
else
    echo "$1 is a file"
fi

names=()
scores=()

while IFS= read -r name score
do
    names+=( "$name" )
    scores+=( "$score" )
done < $inputfile
echo "The arrays before sorting"

for (( i=0; i<${#names[@]}; ++i ))
do
    echo "${names[$i]} ${scores[$i]}"
done

echo "The sorted arrays using bubble sort"
for (( i = 0; i < ${#names[@]}; i++ ))
do
    for (( j = $i; j < ${#names[@]}; j++ ))
    do
            if [ ${names[$i]} -gt ${names[$j]} ]; then #error here
                    t=${names[$i]}
                    names[$i]=${names[$j]}
                    names[$j]=$t
            fi
    done
done

for (( i=o; i<${#names[@]}; ++i ))
do
    echo "${names[$i]}"
done
```

Could someone copy and paste to see if they get the same issue?

Comment: okay I replaced IFS= to IFS= " " and now both arrays are populated. Same error with the sort :( @KamilCuk

Answer (score 0):

> while IFS= read -r name score

is wrong. With `IFS=` no words are not splitted - the  whole line is assigned to `name` and `score` is always empty.

> I cannot seem to find why.

Because you pass multiple arguments to `[`, it expands to for ex `i=0 j=1`:

```
# if [ ${names[$i]} -gt ${names[$j]} ]
# expands to:
if [ Ted 86 -gt Anthony 70 ]
```

No `[` program receives 6 arguments and doesn't know what to do with them - so it exits with an error. When you fix the `IFS` problem mentioned above - still you are comparing *names* as *numbers* with `-gt` - I guess you meant to sort people by their *scores* not by their names.

Comment: I am trying to sort both elements the names, and the score following the same